# cannot connect to work network using OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn

I am running a properly-configured OpenVPN client on Windows Vista (the same config has worked on other computers).  I'm using OpenVPN GUI 1.0.3.

I seem to be properly connected according to OpenVPN UI:

-> Current State: Connected

```
Thu Dec 02 22:20:13 2010 OpenVPN 2.1.3 i686-pc-mingw32 [SSL] [LZO2] [PKCS11] built on Aug 20 2010
Thu Dec 02 22:20:13 2010 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Thu Dec 02 22:20:13 2010 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Thu Dec 02 22:20:14 2010 LZO compression initialized
Thu Dec 02 22:20:14 2010 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Thu Dec 02 22:20:14 2010 UDPv4 link remote: 99.74.115.162:1194
Thu Dec 02 22:20:15 2010 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with 99.74.115.162:1194
Thu Dec 02 22:20:18 2010 TAP-WIN32 device [Local Area Connection 2] opened: \\.\Global\{3BCA7384-B6C5-4E6A-9D11-AF08F49874BC}.tap
Thu Dec 02 22:20:18 2010 Notified TAP-Win32 driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.0.2.10/255.255.255.252 on interface {3BCA7384-B6C5-4E6A-9D11-AF08F49874BC} [DHCP-serv: 10.0.2.9, lease-time: 31536000]
Thu Dec 02 22:20:18 2010 Successful ARP Flush on interface [19] {3BCA7384-B6C5-4E6A-9D11-AF08F49874BC}
Thu Dec 02 22:20:23 2010 WARNING: potential route subnet conflict between local LAN [10.0.0.0/255.255.255.0] and remote VPN [10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0]
Thu Dec 02 22:20:23 2010 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

ipconfig shows that I am connected to my work network:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hq.myworkplace.net
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::25aa:1764:3f5d:9c70%19
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.10
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

If I launch Remote Desktop Connection and try to connect to a machine, it fails.  I tried to connect by using machineName and my using hq.myworkplace.net\machineName.  Pinging that machine also fails (ping machineName, and ping hq.myworkplace.net\machineName error with "Ping request could not find host machineName")

I have a feeling that my wireless router is also causing some problems.

Any suggestion as what I could do next to troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well - as your log says - you have route conflict - your home subnet overlaps with corporate private address range. if possible try readdressing your home network and use for it something from 192.168.0.0/16 or 172.16.0.0/16 ranges.

Comment: Thanks I set up my home network router to use 172.16.0.1 and now I can ping machines and remote desktop into them